# How to use Databinding in Android

Tags: android

In my application I want use this library : https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/SSImagePicker

This library used **dataBinding** true and when add this line into **gradle** show me error.

In my project I use **viewBindig** for access to views and again I added **databinding**!.
**My Gradle :**

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
    dataBinding true
}
```

**Error message :**

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_agp_internal_javaPreCompileDebug_kaptClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:7.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler/7.2.1/databinding-compiler-7.2.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler/7.2.1/databinding-compiler-7.2.1.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler/7.2.1/databinding-compiler-7.2.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'
   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kapt'.
      > Could not find androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:7.2.1.
        Required by:
            project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s
```

After rebuild project show me this error! 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

KeyOk

Go to your gradle file dependencies find and remove this dependency.

```
implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:7.2.1'
```

The error above above is informing you this dependency cannot be found and it is the one causing the error.

This is what the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/databinding) say about Data Binding Library:

> The databinding library is bundled with the Android Gradle plugin. You do not need to declare a dependency on the library, but you must enable it. To enable data binding, set the dataBinding build option to true in your module's build.gradle file, as shown below:

The docs go on to say you need to enable data binding for all modules that depend on libraries that use data binding, even if the module doesn't directly use data binding. This you have already done.

To learn more about the Databinding you can again [check the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) or [this codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-databinding#1)